# ¿Como guardar mi key o semilla de encriptacion en un archivo dll PHP?

Tags: php, encriptación

Tengo una duda que realmente no se que tan posible es, el problema es que estoy desarrollando un programa en PHP y quiero encriptar un key en un archivo dll, esto con el fin de poder llamar ese archivo y usarlo para encriptar datos. Nunca lo he trabajado de esta forma, es posible? He estado buscando en internet pero no logro dar con algo que me guie.

Comment: Guarsar en un archivo dll?

Comment: Si o en un .key, mi intención es no tener la key en el codigo, sino usar el archivo como key, que lo lea para encriptar

Comment: Creo que quizas puedes estar haciendo la pregunta incorrecta. Podrías aclarar exactamente que es lo que pretendes realizar con esto? Es decir, que quieres almacenar en el archivo? que quieres encriptar, cuando lo quieres encriptar/desencriptar? porque? Quizas lo que quieras hacer tenga una mejor solución que la que estás pensando

Comment: Ok, creo que si formule mal mi pregunta, mi intención es poder crear un sistema que antes de enviar la información la encripte y se guarde en la base de datos, pero siento que tener la semilla en un archivo del sistema declarada como variable es inseguro, por eso queria ver la opcion de generar el archivo .key, me explique un poco mejor?

Comment: Ok, estás generando un script de PHP y tienes unos datos, lo que quieres es encriptar los datos antes de almacenarlos en la base de datos. Si lo que te preocupa es que la clave quede en el código, eso lo solucionas facilmente con una variable de entorno, así tienes exactamente el mismo código, pero en tu máquina local la clave puede ser "abc", pero en el servidor puede ser algo mas complejo y completamente distinto. Aunque personalmente no le veo mucho sentido a guardar información encriptada en la base de datos, pues no podrías hacer consultas sobre esos datos luego facilmente.